# Can't update Google Drive file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive using the the **v3** Google Drive SDK:

```
$this->drive()
    ->files
    ->update(
        $this->report->getId(),
        $this->report,  // This is a Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile instance
        [
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'data' => file_get_contents($this->getLocalReportLocation())
        ]
    );
```

And I receive the following exception:

> Error calling PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/ABCDe4FGHvXZTKVOSkVETjktNE0?uploadType=multipart: (403) The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.

Comment: What if you just remove the `data` extra parameter?

Comment: Same issue, so I guess it's not the `data` parameter causing it. Will edit the question.

Comment: also, what is the signature of the `update` method?

Comment: `public function update($fileId, Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $postBody, $optParams = array())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue is caused by `$this->report` which I obtain in the following way:

```
// Fetch the latest synchronized report
$latestReport = $this->drive()
    ->files
    ->listFiles([
        'orderBy' => 'modifiedTime',
        'q'       => '\''.$this->userEmail.'\' in owners AND name contains \'AppName\'',
    ])
    ->getFiles()[0];

$this->report = $this->drive()
    ->files
    ->get($latestReport->id);
```

Probably `$this->report`, which is an instance of `\Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile`, contains some fields that are causing issues when set and passed to the `update()` method.

I was able to solve the problem by passing a new instance of `\Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` to the `update()` method like this:

```
$this->drive()
    ->files
    ->update($this->report->getId(), (new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile()), [
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'data' => file_get_contents($this->getLocalReportLocation()),
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    ]);
```